# Does linq to sql have a with ties option?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to move the following query to Linq-to-sql, is it possible?

```
select * from (
Select top (@Percent) percent with ties *
from(
    Select distinct
      LoanNumber as LoanNo
    From CHE 
    Left Join RecordingInfo as Rec
    On CHE.LoanNumber = Rec.LoanNo
    Where Channel = 'LINX'
        and CHE.Doc in ('MTG','MOD')
        and Rec.LoanNo is null
        and LoanNumber >= '@LoanNo'
) A
order by LoanNo @Order
) B
order by LoanNo
```

I have not seen anyway to do with ties in linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this will work for you.

```
public static IQueryable<T> TopPercentWithTies<T, TKey>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> groupByExpression, double percent)
{
    var groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(groupByExpression);
    int numberToTake = groupedQuery.Count() * percent / 100;
    return groupedQuery.Take(numberToTake).SelectMany(t => t);
}
```

I only tested it with IEnumerable, so I don't know for sure that it'll work properly with IQueryable.  I also sorted the list before calling TopPercentWithTies().

Here's the code I used to test it.

```
int percent = 50;
var people = new []
{
    new { Age = 99, Name = "Adam" },
    new { Age = 99, Name = "Andrew" },
    new { Age = 89, Name = "Bob" },
    new { Age = 50, Name = "Cecil" },
    new { Age = 50, Name = "Doug" },
    new { Age = 50, Name = "Everett" },
    new { Age = 35, Name = "Frank" },
    new { Age = 25, Name = "Greg" },
    new { Age = 15, Name = "Hank" }
};
var sortedPeople = people.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(person => person.Age);
var results = sortedPeople.TopPercentWithTies(person => person.Age, percent);
foreach (var person in results)
    Console.WriteLine(person);
```

Hope it helps or at least gets you in the right direction.  You may want to tweak the logic for calculating numberToTake.

Comment: very nice. although I would expect it would be an extension of IOrderedQueryable.

Comment: Oh sweet.  I didn't know about IOrderedQueryable.  I've updated the code.

Comment: This doesn't look like it would yield results anything like T-SQL `TOP n PERCENT WITH TIES`.  Consider the data `1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 ... 100`, which has 5050 entries. `TOP 1 PERCENT WITH TIES` would return 55 rows (up to value `10`), while your function returns only 1 row.

Comment: Didn't downvote but this answer is not working as `WITH TIES` does. As *Ben Voigt* stated, if you consider data set consisting of `{3 2 2 1 1 0}` the result set will be `{3 2 2 1 1}` where it (as with ties behaviour) should be `{3 2 2}`