# Entity Framework Take() returns more elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can someone please explain why following query returns list of 8 vessels?

```
 var vessels = await db.Vessels
                       .Include(m => m.Images.Select(c => c.Activity))
                       .Include(m => m.VesselAddresses.Select(c => c.Address))
                       .Where(m => m.Images.Any(c => c.Activity.Active))
                       .Where(m => m.Activity.Active)
                       .Where(m => m.Listed)
                       .Where(m => m.Activity.User.Active)
                       .OrderBy(m => Guid.NewGuid())
                       .Take(4)
                       .ToListAsync();
```

If i remove `Include(m => m.VesselAddresses.Select(c => c.Address))` or `OrderBy` from the query, then it works just fine and returns 4 records, but if i leave it as it is, then it returns 8 records, even i specified `Take(4)`

**EDIT**

This is almost the same query for apartments table, but this query works just fine and always returns 4 rows:

```
 var apartments = await db.Apartments
                        .Include(m => m.Images.Select(c => c.Activity))
                        .Include(m => m.Address)
                        .Where(m => m.Images.Any(c => c.Activity.Active))
                        .Where(m => m.Activity.Active)
                        .Where(m => m.Listed)
                        .Where(m => m.Activity.User.Active).OrderBy(m => Guid.NewGuid())
                        .Take(4)
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12065589/4550393. The statement there is: "Remember, an linq-To-Entities query doesn't actually do a roundtrip to the database until a foreach or ToList() is done." May be this gives a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework doesn't run the query you are making until you call the `ToListAsync`, hence my guess would be that you Include can't be translated into SQL so its being ignored by the query builder until after it executes the SQL which because `take` converts into sql as `TOP`, means that the include is being applied after `Take`

moving the .Take(4) after the .ToListAsync() should correct

also i assumed you are using .OrderBy(m => Guid.NewGuid()) to randomise the results i would suggest instead `Random.NextDouble()` guid is overkill for randomisation

Comment: what do you suggest as a solution? If i place Take(2), instead of Take(4), i get a desired effect, but then code looks missleading.

Also, I have apartments table with almost exact same query, and it works just fine.
I will update my question with that info.

Comment: Isn't moving Take(4) after ToListAsync() overkill and will fetch thousands of records to memory instead of just 4?